# Getting undefined Json value

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

PHP:

```
echo json_encode(array('result'=>"tt"));
```

JS:

```
alert('JSON data string is: '+data.result); });
```

Is this code right? Please help

Answer (score 0):

You probably need

```
echo "data = " . json_encode(array('result'=>'tt'));
```

as your PHP.

Comment: $arr = array('a' => 1);
  echo json_encode($arr); tried with php but how do i read it in js?

Comment: Can you modify your question and include all the relevant code including script and PHP tags? Maybe something's wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try

```
var obj={};  //Your object
JSON.stringify(obj);
```

on the client side. It's much easier. (Or use [jQuery](http://www.jquery.ocm/))